# How to make batch file report if there was an error in command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, syntax-error

I would like to make a little file. Here is a small part of the code...

```
@echo off

:hi
set /p "input=>>"
%input%
pause
```

Ok! But now i'd like to add something like this...

```
IF %input% error with execution goto error
IF %input% execution successful goto great
```

Of course I improvised a bit. Any command(s) I could use?

Comment: IIRC there is an `ERRORLEVEL` environment variable you can inspect.

Comment: Hmmmm. Like FRED? I have heard of ERRORLEVEL, but havent seen it be used to find errrors, only to compare variables... How might I structure a ERRORLEVEL analogy? Thanks

Comment: I found [this page](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/errorlevel.php) which might answer your question. If you find a satisfactory solution, you might want to self-answer your question for other people who might stumble upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is also a variable named `%ERRORLEVEL%` which is very useful:

```
@echo off
:hi
set /p "input=>> "
%input%
if %errorlevel%==9009 echo not a valid command & goto :hi
if %errorlevel%==0 echo successful & goto :hi
echo failed with errorlevel %errorlevel%
goto :hi
```

Note : %errorlevel% 9009 means "no such command"; %errorlevel% 0 means "command was successful", any other %errrorlevel% means "error".

Comment: Thanks bro! I researched errorlevel, but never found out about the preset variables! Thanks very much, I appreciate your time reviewing my question and giving me a great answer:)

Comment: When I get some more rep I will definetly up-vote your answer!